# Problem with GlobalClusteringCoefficient

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks

I have a simple problem, I would like to measure the global clustering coefficient for a random graph. Here is my code:

```
GlobalClusteringCoefficient[RandomGraph[DegreeGraphDistribution[
  {2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2,1, 1, 1, 7, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1}], 10000]]
```

This is just supposed to create 10000 random graphs, with each vertex in each graph having a fixed number of edges. The error I get is as follows:

> GlobalClusteringCoefficient::graph: A graph object is expected at position 1 in GlobalClusteringCoefficient

I tried wrapping everything before the clustering function as follows:

```
Graph[[RandomGraph[DegreeGraphDistribution[
  {2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2,1, 1, 1, 7, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1}], 10000]]]
```

And it gives the same error. Anyone know how to convert the random graph generated into a graph object?

EDIT:

So I had in mind to create a For-loop which would go from `i = 1` until `10,000` -- but this saved me a lot of computational power. Now I have this:

```
Mean[GlobalClusteringCoefficient /@ 
  RandomGraph[DegreeGraphDistribution[
    {2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 7, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1}], 10000]]
```

I get a value of `4587/86000`, which is almost too good to be true -- is this really calculating the mean of all 10000 cluster coefficients?

I am a little surprised because I have been using *Mathematica* for a total of one day, but this solved the issue far faster than R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RandomGraph[DegreeGraphDistribution[...], 10000] gives a list of graphs.
You need to map GlobalClusteringCoefficient into that. For example,

```
GlobalClusteringCoefficient /@ 
  RandomGraph[DegreeGraphDistribution[
    {2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 7, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1}], 10]
```

> {3/43, 0, 0, 0, 3/43, 3/43, 3/43, 3/43, 0, 3/43}

Comment: Woah thank you so much, can you check my slightly edited question?

Comment: @user9858 yes, it's computing all 10000 cluster coefficient. you could also do something like this: dist = DegreeGraphDistribution[{2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2,
     2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 7, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1}];

data1 = RandomVariate[
   GraphPropertyDistribution[GlobalClusteringCoefficient[g], 
    g \[Distributed] dist], 1000];

data2 = RandomVariate[
   GraphPropertyDistribution[MeanClusteringCoefficient[g], 
    g \[Distributed] dist], 1000];

Histogram[{data1, data2}]